# Where to find docs for the supported actions for `tell application` statement

Tags: applescript, automator, script

Where to find docs for the supported actions for `tell application` statement. Similar to

```
tell application "Finder" to close every window
```

How can I know that Finder is supported and also `close every window` is one of its actions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know of a *list*, per se, however **AppleScript** supported applications have a **dictionary** that you can view to see what's available to a given application, besides what available in the **StandardAdditions.sdef** file of **Script Editor** itself.

While in **Script Editor** press **⇧⌘L** to bring up the **Library**, where you can double-click on **Finder** to review what's in its **AppleScript** dictionary.

[image: Library]

<sup>The **Library** is also accessible from the **Window** menu while in **Script Editor**.</sup>

---

**Finder's AppleScript dictionary:**

[image: Finder's AppleScript dictionary]

---

For example, looking at the **Standard Suite**, not selected in the image above, you'll see many *verbs* that are supported, one of them being `close`, so:

```
tell application "Finder" to close every window
```

Will indeed close any **Finder** windows that are open.

Comment: And for new users there is always the obligatory "Read the AppleScript Language Guide". But Apple annoyingly seems to no longer host the PDF of this document on their website! So here is a link from another website that is hosting the document:
https://nathangrigg.com/images/2012/AppleScriptLanguageGuide.pdf

Comment: You should add that you can find the scripting dictionary for any app (if it exists) either by dragging the app onto the Script Editor Icon, or selecting File→Open Dictionary (⇧⌘O) in Script Editor.